# How to ignore required properties on PATCH request in C# Web API?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API with the following class as a data model:

```
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I want the `Status` property to be required ONLY for when creating a new `Person` but when updating a `Person` I want to block the option of being able to update its `Status`

So on my `modelBinder` I set it to ignore after save like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.LastName, e.Status }).IsUnique();

    entity.Property(e => e.ID).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Throw);
    entity.Property(e => e.Status).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
});
```

That works greater when I'm sending the entire `Person` object in the `PATCH` request:

```
{
  "personID": "3DF4360C-BFE1-48EB-AAA1-52B9EBFB320E",
  "FirstName": "First",
  "LastName": "Last",
  "Status": "SomeStatus"
}
```

The problem is, that I want the users to be able to send partial updates and not having to send the entire object for every update, like this:

```
{
  "personID": "3DF4360C-BFE1-48EB-AAA1-52B9EBFB320E",
  "FirstName": "First"
}
```

And I'm getting an exception for missing the `Required` Fields.

I found a Nuget package called `FoolProof` that extends the validation attributes and has a validation called `RequiredIfEmpty` that I could use on the `PersonID` to see if I'm creating a new `Person` or updating an existing one but that only work on `string` properties and doesn't work on `Guid`.

I tried to extend the `RequiredIfEmpty` like this:

```
public class RequiredIfInsertAttribute : ContingentValidationAttribute
{
    public RequiredIfInsertAttribute(string dependentProperty)
        : base(dependentProperty) { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value, object dependentValue, object container)
    {
        Guid id = new Guid((dependentValue ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim());
        if (id.IsEmpty())
            return value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString().Trim());

        return true;
    }

    public override string DefaultErrorMessage
    {
        get { return "{0} is required"; }
    }
}
```

And on debug, I do get the `IsValid` to return `true` but I'm still getting the same error of `Required fields missing`. I tried removing the `Required` attribute and I still got the error until I found out the the error comes from the actual declaration of the property as a `string` and not `string?` but I don't want the property to be a `string?` because I want the Database to mark it as `NOT NULL`

I don't want to start and create a different class model for each model I'm updating because there are a lot of models and properties and that will be a mess to have in the code.

Any ideas on how to sort this out?

Comment: Remove the required attribute and do a manual check in the action where the property is required.

Comment: But in your case, I will use tree different classes, `Person`, `CreatingPerson`, `UpdatingPerson`.

Comment: This doesn't fall into the existing code that I have because a lot of it is generic and I can't start doing manual checks for every property of every object.

Comment: Sounds like you should not be using Data Entities on your web layer. Best practice is to create a different DTO for the patch request. It is different than a PUT, so why treat it the same?

Comment: Because I don't want to start duplicating classes with all of their properties. That is not the best practice for code maintenance.

Comment: So why don't you remove the [Required] annotation and override it in the places where you need it? Seems like a more maintainable way than creating your own attributes.

Comment: Turns out it's not only the `[Required]` attribute that gives the error. It's the property declaration itself. It wants me to have it as a nullable string like this ` public string? Status { get; set; }`

Comment: You might try [table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting). Personally I would just use Dapper to make it trivial.

Comment: That because you ignore the best practice here (i'm throwing that word back at as you started using it). The best practice is having different models for different endpoints that should behave differently. Maintainability is not measured in lines of code but often in the ease of usage and things being obvious. You get that with distinct models on the surface.

Comment: And then, when you want to make changes to the model you need to go and update all the models that are related to the same entity. Code duplication is neve a best practice.

Comment: Don't use the same type as the API DTO and the Database Entity. The API has *very* different requirements from the Entity. While trying to avoid non-existent duplication, you ended up coupling two different concerns

Comment: Mike Amundsen explained this in a single tweet: [remember, when designing your #WebAPI, your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model #API360](https://twitter.com/mamund/status/767212233759657984)

Comment: I agree with that, but I wanted to avoid having to maintain 2 objects for each table in the DB

Comment: Those aren't tables, they're your messages. PATCH is a diff to begin with, so its model contains only changes. Since you have different requirements for each operation, you can't use the same static validation. At the very least you need FluentValidation

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention that I'm using EF Core with Code-First so those are my DB tables

Comment: No they aren't. ORM means Object to Relational Mapper, not Embedded SQL. No matter how you configure your ORM, it still only works with objects that get mapped to actual tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this to meet my requirements. I distinguish between the configuration of the data model in the DB and the one that is used for the API by defining the DB configuration in the `OnModelCreating` method located in the `MyDatabaseContext.cs` file.

So what I did looks like this:

In the `OnModelCreating` I'm defining the table like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.PersonID).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Throw);
    entity.Property(e => e.FirstName).IsRequired(); //This means that for the DB it is set as NOT NULL
    entity.Property(e => e.LastName).IsRequired(); //This means that for the DB it is set as NOT NULL
    entity.Property(e => e.Status).IsRequired().Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore); // This is prevent the field from being updated after it is inserted.
});
```

And the `Person` class for the API is defined like this

```
using FoolProof.Core;

public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid? ID { get; set; }
    
    [RequiredIfEmpty(nameof(PartnerID))]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; } //This can be nullable here for the API
    
    [RequiredIfEmpty(nameof(PartnerID))]
    public string? LastName { get; set; } //This can be nullable here for the API
    
    [RequiredIfEmpty(nameof(PartnerID))]
    public string? Status { get; set; } //This can be nullable here for the API
}
```

I distinguish between an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE` by Using `RequiredIfEmpty` by `FoolProof` to check if the request body contains a Person `ID`.

For me, this solved the issue.